# Is there a name for disingenuous correlation?

Tags: epidemiology, confounding

Just heard on [on this segment](https://youtu.be/XOWNsIlTZyg?t=16m2s) of a Fox News show hosted by [Tucker Carlson](https://youtu.be/tjTajJZEjqA?t=5m37s) that in recent years gun ownership has gone up while gun-related violence has gone down. Just like that. Followed by the remark "it's just a simple way to do a simple correlation."

The channel is not devoted to truth and analysis, but what are the technical flaws in this argument if it were to be taken seriously even for a second?

[Spurious correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_relationship) seems like a good label, although in this case the poor definition of the two variables is so appalling that there is little point in searching for antecedent or intervening variables.

The issue here is that the definition of crime is left vague on purpose: is he measuring the number of victims of mass shootings (this seems to be on the rise); or is he referring to urban gun violence (which seems to have decreased)?

There has to be a different epidemiology term for comparing two trends that share an instrumental point in common (i.e. guns), but that have otherwise no relation whatsoever. There are adjectives that come to mind, but they are not technical, or restrained.

Comment: This is called someone being vague. That's it.

Comment: it's not helpful to lump all gun related injuries together. most are either accidental or suicides, and gun ownership rate must impact these directly. in case of suicides it doesn't mean that people stop killing themselves, but it certainly make it less likely that they'll shoot themselves. the other injuries should not be directly (or linearly) dependent on gun ownership rates, i mean intentional ones such as murders

Comment: Spurious has a specific meaning: apparently legit on the surface but in fact false. "Crude" or "confounded" is another term for correlations that fail to account for other measures, and may imply that the true trend is not yet known. Also: "You mentioned the Navy, for example, and that we have fewer ships than we did in 1916. Well, Governor, we also have fewer horses and bayonets, because the nature of our military's changed." - Then Senator Obama

Comment: If the correlation is due to a third underlying variable then it is what Yule first called a nonsense correlation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call it what it is,  BS . http://callingbullshit.org/

Comment: P.S. The URL provides the answer, so this is not a link-only answer, and will still be valid even if the link goes dead. So please don't anyone edit this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I won’t deny that I'm stealing from *The Big Bang Theory* here...but I do like the term “specious”.

Comment: Is it possible to add some examples of usage in real life to support this answer?